# ¿Cómo automatizar esta conversión de archivos con un Archivo por Lotes de Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

Necesito convertir varios archivos pero el programa solo se puede usar a través de la línea de comandos con ciertos parámetros.
La estructura del comando es la siguiente:

```
"dca-rs.exe --raw --i <archivo>.wav > <archivo>_<archivo>.dca
```

La cuestión es que quiero automatizar ese proceso con cada uno de los archivos de una sub-carpeta llamada input de manera que el comando quedaría así:

```
dca-rs.exe --raw --i ./input/<archivo>.wav > ./output/<archivo>_<archivo>.dca
```

Por ejemplo si fuese "prueba.wav" sería:

```
dca-rs.exe --raw --i ./input/prueba.wav > ./output/prueba_prueba.dca
```

Pero eso con cada uno de los archivos en esa sub-carpeta.
¿Cómo puedo automatizar ese proceso para que convierta todos los archivos de la carpeta input y ejecute ese comando?

Gracias de antemano.

UPDATE: Resuelta, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola Cahema, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Primero, pasate por el [tour] donde aprenderás como funciona el sitio. Para más informacion tienes [ask] y [help]. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado. Con las pruebas que has hecho, explicanos si te da errores, o resultados inesperados. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un bucle que recorra los archivos, y lo puedes hacer con el siguiente código general:

```
for %%f in (directorio\ruta\*) do ( lo que quieras ejecutar )
```

Por lo que tu código final puede ser algo como:

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%f in (C:\prueba\*.txt) do (
  dca-rs.exe --raw --i ./input/%%f.wav > ./output/%%f_%%f.dca
)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!
Lo he editado un poco pero funciona perfectamente además de que me ha quedado bastante claro.
Te lo agradezco mucho.