# ¿Cómo eliminar la extensión de varios archivos con un Archivo de Lotes de Windows?

Tags: windows, batch

Necesito eliminar la extensión de archivo de todos los archivos de una carpeta.

Digamos que tengo `prueba.txt, prueba2.txt, prueba3.txt, etc...`
Y lo que querría obtener es `prueba, prueba2, prueba3, etc...` sin extensiones de archivo.

He probado a usar el comando ren pero no consigo hacer que elimine solo la extensión de archivo.

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: se me olvidó mencionar que todos los archivos a renombrar se encuentran en una sub-carpeta llamada input.
No es en la misma carpeta que estaría el Archivo de Lotes

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
@ECHO OFF
ren ./input/* ./input/*:.wav =
```

Me dice que el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

UPDATE: Resuelta, gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola Cahema, antes en [tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/83633/15855) te pedi que mostraras lo que habias intentado.. aun asi te respondieron. Ahora vuelves a hacerlo. Por favor, muestra eso que dices del comando `ren` asi como los fallos que te generó. un saludo

Comment: Ups, lo siento no lo leí en el otro post.
He actualizado el post con lo que he intentado.

Comment: Ponlo en la pregunta. Los comentarios no deberian tener informacion relevante para la resolucion de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Renombrar sin extensión

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%f in (C:\prueba\*.txt) do (
ren %%f %%~nf
)
pause
```

El código arriba expuesto recorre el directorio `C:\prueba\` filtrando los archivos por la extensión `.txt`, y ejecuta un `ren` para renombrar los archivos con su mismo nombre pero sin extensión.

## Explicación

El código más sencillo para obtener el nombre sin extensión de un archivo es:

```
@echo %~n0
```

Donde **0** es la variable donde almacenamos el nombre del archivo (que recorres en el **LOOP**), y `n` es un modificador que devuelve el nombre del archivo sin extensión.

Te comparto un cuadro con más referencias que se pueden utilizar en un búcle LOOP: (referenciado y traducido de [SOes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636391/6104382)

> Se pueden utilizar las siguientes variables de referencia para un ciclo FOR:
>
> ```
> %~I         - devuelve %I removiendo cualquier comilla doble (").
> %~fI        - devuelve %I con su nombre de ruta completo.
> %~dI        - devuelve %I solo su letra de unidad.
> %~pI        - devuelve %I solo su ruta.
> %~nI        - devuelve %I solo su nombre de archivo.
> %~xI        - devuelve %I solo su extensión de archivo.
> %~sI        - devuelve ruta con nombre abreviados.
> %~aI        - devuelve %I los atributos del archivo.
> %~tI        - devuelve %I la fecha/hora del archivo.
> %~zI        - devuelve %I el peso del archivo.
> ```

Comment: Gracias nuevamente!
Esto me ha funcionado a la perfección.
Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda de nuevo!

Comment: @cahema No hay porque las dos preguntas son de muy buena calidad, y espero haber redactado una respuesta acorde. Creo que para cualquier persona que se encuentre con el mismo inconveniente y lo busque va a poder salir beneficiada también!

Comment: hola tengo el mismo problema de las extensiones de cahema y utilice el codigo de Agustin M. @ECHO OFF
for %%f in (C:\prueba\*.txt) do (
ren %%f %%~nf
)
pause y al ejecutar el archivo .bat me salia el error "sintaxis incorrecta". obviamente cambie el nombre de la carpeta (prueva) y el de la extension y ahora al cambiar la extensión de los archivos a la de la extension original no los abre y me sale el mensaje de archivo dañado o corrupto. por favor si me pueden ayudar. Tengo un gran problema... .